# Wandering CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: objective-c

Okay this is about to make me insane -- any help would be appreciated. I have two images which are part of a timer application. One is the needle/hand and the other is a little hub which is styled to look like the needle base. I'm using a CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotate the needle and the base stays stationary. The problem: there is like a 1-2px 'wander' to the needle's rotation which makes it look like it's moving off center in relation to the base. I have worked the base and needle image over in PS extensively, and both are dead center pixel wise -- seriously. My method to rotate the hand:

```
-(IBAction) rotateSteamArrow{

 CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( degreesSteam / 180.0 *   3.14159265);
 degreesSteam = degreesSteam + 1.5;
  if (degreesSteam <= 180) {
  [steamNeedle setTransform:rotate];
  }
  else {
   [self handleSteamTimer];
   [self toggleButton:(id)timerButton];
   [self switchSound];
  }


 }
```

Comment: Why not use CoreAnimation or UIView animation blocks?

Comment: I can see that's an option, but even if I switch to using CA I still want to know what's up CGAffineTransform/rotate. Is there something about it which causes this? This is, I think, the most simple kind of image rotate -- basically just rotating it on it's axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with the views anchorpoint until it no longer wobbles.